# Placing images in an already existing matplotlib axis side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib

Starting from an already existing matplotlib figure I added a footer by appending a small axis to the bottom. The idea is to fill this footer with an arbitrary number of logos. I want to place the logos side by side (separated by a user controllable pad parameter) so that they fill the footer in height, thus computing their width so as to maintain the aspect ratio locked.

This is a standalone MRE which summarizes my approach

```py
from matplotlib.image import imread as read_png
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, OffsetImage

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6, 6))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_axis_off()

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 100),
                   np.linspace(-2.0, 2.0, 100))
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X * 10)**2 - (Y * 10)**2)
z = Z1 * 30 + 50 * Z2

cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, z, cmap='PuBu_r')

ax_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
ax_footer = ax_divider.append_axes(
        "bottom", size="10%", pad=0.1)
ax_footer.set_axis_off()

def add_logo(ax, logo, zoom, pos):
    img_logo = OffsetImage(read_png(logo), zoom=zoom)
    logo_ann = AnnotationBbox(
        img_logo, pos, xycoords='axes fraction',
        frameon=False, box_alignment=(0, 0.25))
    at = ax.add_artist(logo_ann)
    return at

add_logo(ax_footer,
         cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.jpg'),
         zoom=0.07,
         pos=(0, 0))

add_logo(ax_footer,
         cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.jpg'),
         zoom=0.07,
         pos=(0.2, 0))

plt.show()
```

which produces

[image]

However I have to explicitly set up `zoom` and `pos` so that the figures occupy the right space.
Is there a way to automatically compute these parameters so that the figures are automatically placed next to each other and they fill the footer axis? Or maybe there is a better approach to that?

I saw many examples defining a subplots with different rows and columns to place the figures but I already have the axis. I haven't found any way to split an already existing axis into an arbitrary number of inset axes of the same width.

-------- EDIT --------------

Expanding on the amazing answer of Jody Klymak this is my "final" version. Once you have a generic axis to put the logos in (I still use `make_axes_locatable` and `append_axes`) you can just use this function

```py
def add_logos(ax, logos, x_padding=10):
    left = 0
    for _, logo in enumerate(logos):
        imdata = read_png(logo)
        w = imdata.shape[1]
        h = imdata.shape[0]
        ax.imshow(imdata,
                  extent=[left, left + w, 0, h])
        left = left + w + x_padding

    # set the limits, otherwise the focus in on the last image
    ax.set_xlim(0, left)
    ax.set_ylim(0, h)
    # anchor the fixed aspect-ratio axes on the left.
    ax.set_anchor('W')
```

To be used as

```py
add_logos(ax_footer, ["../input/logos/Logonuovo.png",
                      "../input/logos/earth_networks_logo.png"])
```

Comment: This is under-specified.  Do you know in advance how many logos there will be?  Do the logo axes edges need to be aligned with the top axes edges?  Do you want the logos to be left-justified, centred, right-justified?

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd just use subfigure: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html

Comment: @JodyKlymak I will pass between 1 to 3 logos to the function, it depends on the figure I'm producing. They should just be stacked side by side starting from the left. I don't need something precise, just something that will fit them into the axis side by side so that I don't have to specify the zoom and positions myself. I saw subfigures some time ago but I seem to remember it was harder to implement than just an axis divider, so that's why I chose this solution at that time. I was hoping for a way to split this footer axis and place the images inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a bit of book keeping, and `buffer` is hardwired, but it stacks images next to each other in a relatively straightforward way.  Do `ax_footer.set_axis_on()` to see what is going on more clearly.  But basically this puts all the logos on an axes, and uses the `extent` keyword argument of `imshow` to place them appropriately.

Note this is relatively robust to different sized logos.  If you want the logos aligned vertically, you can do that too.

There are ways to do this with `HPacker`s etc, but they are needlessly complicated in my opinion.

```py
from matplotlib.image import imread as read_png
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic([['a'], ['b']], height_ratios=[1, 0.3],
                              figsize=(4, 4), layout='constrained')

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 100),
                   np.linspace(-2.0, 2.0, 100))
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X * 10)**2 - (Y * 10)**2)
z = Z1 * 30 + 50 * Z2

ax = axs['a']
cs = ax.contourf(X, Y, z, cmap='PuBu_r')
ax.set_axis_off()

ax_footer = axs['b']
ax_footer.set_axis_off()

nlogo = 3
left = 0
buffer = 30
maxy = -100

for i in range(nlogo):
    logo = cbook.get_sample_data('grace_hopper.jpg')
    imdata = read_png(logo)[:-(i*80+1), :]

    w = imdata.shape[1]
    h = imdata.shape[0]

    ax_footer.imshow(imdata, extent=[left, left + w, 0, h])

    left = left + w + buffer
    maxy = np.max([maxy, h])

# set the limits, otherwise the focus in on the last image
ax_footer.set_xlim(0, left)
ax_footer.set_ylim(0, maxy)

# anchor the fixed aspect-ratio axes on the left.
ax_footer.set_anchor('W')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You're a genius! This is exactly what I was looking for! Only modification I made is to get rid of the `maxy` parameter because I don't want to add an additional padding to the y axis but just use the logo height. Plus I cleaned a little bit everything and put everything into a function. The amazing thing is that this approach only requires the padding on the x axis (`buffer`, and this is completely fine as it was a requirement) and works flawlessly when you scale the picture (or the axis) to a different size.

Comment: There's only one minor issue. I was placing also some text on this footer axis, but since now we're changing the xlimit obviously this text is placed next to the last logo. Is there a way to anchor a text to the rightmost part of the axis still? I'm using something like `ax_footer.text`

Comment: If I needed a piece of text on the right side, I’d make a third axis to go next to the logo axis.

Comment: yeah that's what I wanted to do already but this was the problem I had at the beginning..How can I append an axis to the right of the one containing the logos so that it snaps on the right of the figure but does not ad additional space?

Comment: Hmmm, you didn't mention the extra text in the original.  I don't understand the confusion about adding a third axis.  Just do `subplot_mosaic([['a', 'a'], ['b', 'c']])`.   If you aren't familiar with Matplotlib axes, please see https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/arranging_axes.html

Comment: I do know a little bit about mpl axes, the problem is that I first create the figure and then subsequently need to append different axes to it. This is the reason why in the example I used an axis divider, because this allows me to append axes to the right, bottom or top part of the figure without the need to define a new figure. I know it sounds confusing but this small part of code is used in a big project and I can't really change much in the way the figure is created in the beginning. I was trying to find anything that would let me nest axes into an already existing axis.

Comment: @Droid, in modern matplotlib that is simply done with `inset_axes`.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html. Perhaps also https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html#defining-the-axes-positions-using-inset-axes

Comment: You're right, I did consider `inset_axes` at some point but somehow couldn't convince myself it was the easiest option. I'll try again. Thanks!

Comment: If you use `annotate` rather than `text`, you get a lot more control over placement.  E.g. add this before the `plt.show()` to line up the text with the right of the main axes and the top of the footer axes: `ax_footer.annotate('My Text', (1, 1), xycoords=(ax.transAxes, ax_footer.transAxes), ha='right', va='top')`

Comment: Wow @RuthC, thanks for the perfect suggestion! It never occurred to me I could could use different axes coordinates systems in x and y. I tried to use the ax.TransAxes transform to put the annotation at the beginning but obviously it was not perfect. This works flawlessly as far as my testing goes, so I think I will implement it into production. Is there any downsides associated to not creating a new axis dedicated only to this text but just annotate an already existing one?

Comment: @Droid I do not know of a downside, but I also do not know everything there is to know about Matplotlib!